# Meshes appear traslucent/white when they are not

Tags: rendering, mesh, eevee-render-engine

I was using blender when I accidentally switched to cycles instead of eevee, and the program crashed.
After restarting blender and seeing that the engine already switched back to eevee, I noticed that the mesh that I imported from an .svg, which has been extruded, appears as white/translucent, light passes through.
I tried messing with the materials but nothing worked, everything seems normal and not out of the ordinary.
I don't know what to do, i want to go back to how it was before the crash (object appeared black and blocked the light from behind), I'm a beginner btw
Oh and all of this problems are present in the viewport only, when I render, it seems to be correct, but I can't work on stuff that I can't see until when it's done.
Help please, it's urgent
Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking here to see if you can recover the previous state of your scene.

[image]

Comment: I tried, but to no avail, unfortunately the auto saves don't do anything, the problem persists